# SQL: Populate table column depending on criteria of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I have a SQL table with two fields: Proportion and Explanation.

The Proportion column is populated through a stored procedure and is a decimal (7,2) field. If the Proportion < 0, I want to output "Negative proportion" to the Explanation column, and I am wondering what the best way to do this is.

The problem is, the Explanation column needs to remain editable (therefore not a computed column). As in, users still need to be able to update this column with their own text in which some cases it will be just adding on to the "Negative proportion" text that's already in this field.

What are my best options for doing this?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Do you mean you want the value of the explanation column to change when the value of `Proportion` changes? When should it be updated? When ever it changes (i.e. from `-1` to `-11`), when it changes from >0 to <0 or 0? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Best approach I think in this case is to create a `sql function` to handle this task.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  Default values for columns cannot be expressions with other columns.  You can implement that using a trigger or at the application level.

Another method would be to have a "hidden" column:

```
create table t (
    proportion decimal(10, 2),
    _explanation varchar(255),
    explanation as (case when _explanation is null and proportion < 0 then 'Negative proportion' end)
);
```

This does not require triggers, but you need to insert into `_explanation`.  You can implement similar logic using a view:

```
create table t (
    proportion decimal(10, 2),
    explanation varchar(255)
);

create view v_t as 
    select proportion, 
           (case when explanation is null and proportion < 0 then 'Negative proportion' end) as explanation
    from t;
```

Comment: I think I am going to look at implementing it as a stored procedure. It will check for NULL explanation columns, check if Proportion <0 and then insert "Negative proportion" if so. I believe this could work.